# Terraforming Mars—Hellas Placement Bonus

Tags: terraforming-mars

In the Hellas board expansion, placing a tile in the middle of the bottommost row grants the player a placement bonus of 1 ocean tile at the expense of 6 MegaCredits. If all ocean tiles have been placed, would the player just lose 6 MegaCredits and not gain the bonus of placing an ocean tile?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to the Hellas map, the [rules for Hellas and Elysium](https://www.richardahart.com/wp-content/uploads/games/TerraformingMars/TerraformingMars-HellasAndElysium-Rules.pdf) state:

> The other special bonus is on the South Pole itself, requiring you to pay 6 megacredits for placing a tile here, but giving you an ocean tile...

Since the cost is not what you pay to receive the ocean tile, and is instead the price for playing on that space, you are correct in assuming that if all the ocean tiles have already run out, a player putting something on that spot will pay 6 MC, and not receive an additional bonus.